# Editing vmlinuz file in linux

Tags: linux, installation, boot

I'm new to linux.
I want to edit "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.Unable to boot - Please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU" from vmlinuz file(RHEL6.0)
If editing this message is possible Can anyone suggest a way to modify message.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to modify that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is in [/arch/.../boot/cpu.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/boot/cpu.c) in the linux kernel source. You can modify it, [recompile the kernel](http://linuxfocus.berlios.de/English/July2002/article252.shtml) and install the new kernel.

Comment: **recompile the kernel** and the OP says **I'm new to linux**. Just kidding. Mostly (s)he was expecting something like editing config files in **/etc**

Comment: One would hope that, new to Linux or not, that the OP would understand that editing an error message will not make the underlying error go away.

Answer (score 2):

you can grep the kernel sources for this string, and replace it with whatever you want, and then recompile your kernel. Usually replacing a string directly inside a binary (though it is technically possible), especially for the kernel is a very bad idea

Comment: Your answer is somewhat contradictory as for the kernel usually there is no other way to modify a string.